# Why is one JPA entity complaining about modifying the identifier while another is not?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, java-17

I am working on an authorization microservice using Springboot. I have the notion of permissions, roles, and users, each of which is represented as an `@Entity` class with a corresponding `JpaRepository`.

Each `@Entity` class has an `@IdClass` that consists of a string ID and a timestamp (the field is called `createdAt`). The idea is that any modifications to one of the entity objects will create a new row in the database. I am unable to modify this database schema. I ran into the issue where modifying the ID (the timestamp portion) on updates threw a `HibernateExeption`. My solution was to use `@PrePersist` to modify the timestamp.

```
  @PrePersist
  private void updateTimestamp() {
    createdAt = Instant.now();
  }
```

This seemed to work for my permissions entity. However, when I test updating my role entity, I am now getting the following error

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of com.example.auth.model.Role was altered from RoleId(roleId=TEST_ROLE_R2, createdAt=2023-09-04T21:52:39.860899Z) to RoleId(roleId=TEST_ROLE_R2, createdAt=2023-08-31T23:12:25.927743Z)
```

with the same `@PrePersist` method.

Another thing that is odd is that the exception seems to get thrown when accessing the permission repository. When updating/creating a role, the information for the associated permissions is referenced.

Where the exception is thrown

```
permissionRepository.findMostRecentPermissionById(p)
```

`findMostRecentPermisisonById()`

```
    @Query(
        value = "SELECT * FROM auth.permissions WHERE permissionID = :permissionID ORDER BY createdat DESC LIMIT 1",
        nativeQuery = true
    )
    Permission findMostRecentPermissionById(String permissionID);
```

I am not sure what is causing the exception to be thrown at all, and am especially confused as to why it is being thrown here. The `findMostRecentPermissionById` method does not cause any issues when used in other parts of the code. Any insight or advice would be much appreciated.

### Update

I still do not understand why the exception was thrown where it was. However, using `entityManager.detach(entity)` allows me to manually set the timestamp field and add a new entity.

Comment: First, it isn't clear, are you modifying an exiting entity instance's createdBy date trying to get a new row inserted? Where is that createdAt=2023-09-04T21:52:39.860899Z date coming from? As the error states, you cannot update an existing entity's ID values; JPA will cache entities, and with change tracking, is likely detecting that this was an existing entity previously read in. If that is what you are attempting, you should instead create a copy with the timestamp left blank to let the pre-persist set it.

Comment: @Chris I am adding a new entity. I am confused why the exception is thrown because the line in the stack trace points to unrelated code. Nevertheless, as described in my update, I am now using entityManager.detach() to remove the object from the persistence context and then manually setting the timestamp.

Comment: So you were reading in an entity, modifying it and then trying to call persist? Detach  might work, but you might also get into problems with change tracking (provider/implementation specific)- you are better off making a copy of the entity to persist as a new instance instead. As for when the exception occurs - persist/save does not require immediate inserts to the database. Instead, the JPA provider can delay statements until required to synchronize to the database (ie on flush or transaction commit, or queries that require synchronization)

Comment: @Chris my understanding is TC's goal is to create versions implicitly: the idea is when JPA have discovered dirty entity and is trying to flush that entity it supposed to update `createdAt` field which is part of composite PK and start considering that entity as new one. No doubts, performing detach (or other tricks) is turning that "implicit magic" into some kind of explicit code, which is actually expressed in wrong words

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about the correctness of your schema design - typically such desires (i.e. maintaining a set of object versions and querying the latest one primarily) are being implemented via more complex approaches, for example:

```
object_id, // unique identifier of version
chronicle_id, // identifier of root version
antecedent_id, // identifier of previous version
latest_flag // denotes the latest version
```

Nevertheless, Hibernate does not support changing entity identifier, that is stated clearly in [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/mappingGuide/en-US/html/ch06.html):

> Hibernate and JPA both make the following assumptions about the corresponding database column(s):
>
> - UNIQUE - The values must uniquely identify each row.
> - NOT NULL - The values cannot be null. For composite ids, no part can be null.
> - IMMUTABLE - The values, once inserted, can never be changed. This is more a general guide, than a hard-fast rule as opinions vary. JPA defines the behavior of changing the value of the identifier attribute to be undefined; **Hibernate simply does not support that**. In cases where the values for the PK you have chosen will be updated, Hibernate recommends mapping the mutable value as a natural id, and use a surrogate id for the PK. See Chapter 7, Natural Ids.

Technically, the above is stated for columns in database, but the same applies for entity classes as well.

**Answering the initial question "Why does it sometimes work and sometimes does not?"**

The actual behaviour depends on whether the entity to be modified is known to persistent context or not, if persistent context has no information about entity to be modified it considers that entity as new and everything works "as expected", otherwise exception gets thrown, for example:

```
class EntityService {


  private EntityRepo entityRepo;

  // this throws exception
  // because spring maintains single session (persistence context)
  // per transaction, so both  entityRepo.findById and entityRepo.save
  // calls share the same instance of persistence context

  @Transactional
  void save1() {
     Entity entity = entityRepo.findById(...);
     entity.updateTimestamp();
     entityRepo.save(entity);
  }

  // this method does not throw exception
  // because entityRepo.findById and entityRepo.save calls
  // do not share the same instance of persistence context

  // @Transactional (propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  void save2() {
     Entity entity = entityRepo.findById(...);
     entity.updateTimestamp();
     entityRepo.save(entity);
  }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. The bit about the persistence context was very helpful.

I was able to get my code to work by creating a new persistence context around the method that has a call to `permissionRepository.findMostRecentPermissionById()`. However, I'm still not sure why that helps. Why would the persistence context matter if the only thing that is in a new context is a read only database interaction to a different JPA repository? The method that is fetching and modifying the role and then calling `repo.save(roleEntity)` is all still in the same context.